# Centrifugal force on body in motion in space

Tags: classical-mechanics, centrifugal-force

I'm trying to understand the motion of a body in space for simulation purposes and wondering if my understanding of centrifugal force is correct.

Imagine a body in space with no gravitional/EM forces acting on it. The body is a ship that can apply thrust along different axes (X+, X-, Y+, Y-, Z+, Z-). The body starts from rest by applying a thrust force along X-. It achieves a certain velocity (along X+) and turns off the thrust force. It now wants to move along Y+ direction, hence it applies a thrust in Y- direction.

To an observer sitting at an absolute position (somewhere above the plane of the ship and looking down Z-), will the ship be now moving at a line 45deg to its previous path?

Or, will there be a centrifugal force acting on the ship, thus throwing the ship outwards along radius of curvature? And to actually make the desired turn the ship will have to apply an additional thrust that will point to center of curvature?

Is the later observation same as the train moving on earth surface along a curved path, hence needing an angle of bank to avoid going off course?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ship can apply thrust along +x,-x,+y,-y,+z & -z. After reaching a velocity $v$ in the +x direction, the thrust is switched off. Now if thrust is switched on along -y direction, the body will first traverse a curved path during acceleration until it makes an angle with the +x direction attaining some velocity $v'$ in the +y direction when the thrust is switched off. The body will go along that direction with a constant velocity of $(v^2+v'^2)^{1/2}$. If the thrusts are identical the angle will be $45^o$ and $v=v'$. During the curved motion objects in the ship will experience a pseudo force (but not centrifugal force) in the -y direction.

If the ship can apply thrust along all directions then, the thrust can be applied in such a way that it is always along the radius of curvature of the path of the ship, radially outward applying force on the ship radially inward. In this case objects in the ship will experience a centrifugal force (is a pseudo force) radially outwards.

Comment: I tend to agree with what you said. Let me rephrase the question, when will a moving body in space experience a centrifugal force? If `v1`,`p1` and `v2`,`p2` are velocities and positions of body at `t1` and `t2` and `v2!=v1`, will the body be traversing a circular arc where (`p2-p1` being arc length), hence the ship or the objects in the ship experience a centrifugal force?

Comment: Let me add to my comment above. If `v2` and `v1` only differ in magnitude then the psuedo force will be linear and won't be called centrifugal force, but if they differ in direction then the psuedo force will be centrifugal. Does that sound right?

Answer (score 0):

You refer to the observer with the absolute position. I know what you mean. Let us called that “laboratory coordinate system”. In principle each inertial system is equivalent to all other ones (as long as they are at rest or moving continuously). People tried to establish an absolute coordinate system but you cannot find any such system. However, you can *define* a particular system to be the one of reference, that is just fine.

Now the coordinate system that you choose is not accelerated. This means that it is an inertial system and there are no fictitious forces. In this system, there simply is no centrifugal force. Therefore you are right with your $45^\circ$ idea.

You have the basic relation of (non-relativistic) acceleration:
$$ \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} \vec v = \vec a$$
where $\vec a$ is the acceleration and $\vec v$ is the velocity. For the velocity you have
$$ \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} \vec x = \vec v$$
where $\vec x$ is the current position of the ship.

These relations can be integrated via time and you get the following:
$$ \vec v(t) = \vec v_0 + \int_{0}^t \vec a(t') \, \mathrm d t' \,.$$

This means that the velocity that you have at time $t$ in your simulation is the starting velocity $\vec v_0$ of the spaceship as well as the integrated action of all the accelerations up to this point.

You say that the ship should move along the $x$ direction at first and then try to change course to the $y$ direction by applying thrust along the $y$ direction. This means that the acceleration in the first part of the simulation is
$$ \vec a_1 = \tilde a \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
and later on
$$ \vec a_1 = \tilde a \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \,.$$
The factor $\tilde a$ is the acceleration magnitude of the spaceship's thrusters.

Say the thrust is applied for a period $T$ from $t = 0$ to $t = T$. And the ship starts from rest (with respect to that observer) so we also have $\vec v_0 = \vec 0$. The integral
$$ \vec v(T) = \int_{0}^T \vec a(t') \, \mathrm d t'$$
simplifies to
$$ \vec v(T) = \int_{0}^T \begin{pmatrix} \tilde a  \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \, \mathrm d t'$$
and that is the integration of a constant, hence just
$$ \vec v(T) = \begin{pmatrix} \tilde a T \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \,.$$

Now we do the integration to the next timestep to go from $T$ to $2T$. This will then be
$$ \vec v(2T) = \begin{pmatrix} \tilde a T \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + \int_{T}^{2T} \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \tilde a   \end{pmatrix} \, \mathrm d t' \,.$$
We can integrate and obtain
$$ \vec v(2T) = \begin{pmatrix} \tilde a T \\ \tilde a T \end{pmatrix}
= \tilde a T \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \,. $$

You see that this is exactly the vector with the $45^\circ$ angle that you thought about.

In order to get the motion into a pure $y$ direction, you would have to apply thrust like
$$\tilde a \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \,.$$
If you integrate that and add the previous velocity that was in pure $x$ direction to it, you get pure $y$ movement.

In the simulation you would take the differential equations at the beginning (the ones with $\vec x$, $\vec v$ and $\vec a$) and integrate them step by step. So at each point you would have $\vec a$ and compute $\Delta \vec v = \vec a \Delta t$ where the $\Delta t$ has to be chosen such that it is fine enough to give smooth results and big enough that your computer will eventually be able to finish.

In case you further want to look into this, take a look at Runge-Kutta integration methods, they are more accurate but more involved as the Euler method I just described.

A couple years back I programmed a simulation like you described. It is [on my website](http://martin-ueding.de/en/projects/quasar/index.html) and you can download the compiled Java code and run it (if you sufficiently trust me with that). I invite you to look into the source code.

For instance in the [code for the spaceship](https://github.com/martin-ueding/quasar/blob/master/Schiff.java) you see what I mean with iterating the differential equation:

```
public void move() {
    this.vx += this.ax;
    this.vy += this.ay;
    this.vr += this.ar;

    if (Quasar.gravity) {
        this.vy += this.g;
    }
    this.x += this.vx;
    this.y += this.vy;
    this.a += this.vr;
}
```

The gravity is included and it will make the ship fall down (although the background picture suggests wide open space).

To come back to the centrifugal force: You do not have to think about centrifugal force for a freely moving spaceship. The centrifugal force will appear when you take the system of the spaceship (not an inertial system in general) and the spaceship rotates. The centrifugal force will be what presses the astronauts to the outer hull of the ship and provides some sort of artificial gravity.

Motion on earth is simple if one approximates the surface of earth to be at rest. If you look closely you will find a bit of centrifugal force and the Coriolis force. These are fictitious forces only, so they would not be included by a “god” coordinate system or any other inertial system.

---

Here is a simple simulation of the situation with thrust in $x$ and then in $y$ direction.

This is what the ship does. First row is the position $x$ and $y$. The second row is the velocity in $x$ and $y$-direction. And the last row is the thrust applied to each direction.

http://chaos.stw-bonn.de/users/mu/uploads/2016-01-15/fig1.svg

For some reason the axes labels are not shown in the SVG. You can also [download the PDF](http://chaos.stw-bonn.de/users/mu/uploads/2016-01-15/fig1.pdf) to see it in full.

And this what the observer looking down would see:

http://chaos.stw-bonn.de/users/mu/uploads/2016-01-15/fig2.svg

[Download PDF](http://chaos.stw-bonn.de/users/mu/uploads/2016-01-15/fig2.pdf)

You can see that from time 0 to 10 in the $x$ direction you have a parabola. After time 10 there is no acceleration in $x$ and you only have a constant velocity and therefore travel on a straight line. Between 10 and 20 you have acceleration only in the $y$ direction. After time 20 the ship flies on a straight line again.

You can either download the [full source code](http://chaos.stw-bonn.de/users/mu/uploads/2016-01-15/ship.py) or look at it here:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Copyright © 2016 Martin Ueding <dev@martin-ueding.de>
# Licensed under The MIT License

import argparse

import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import numpy as np


def main():
    options = _parse_args()

    # List of times as well as x and y coordinates the ship was at. This is
    # needed to draw the trajectory later on.
    ts = []
    xs = []
    ys = []
    vxs = []
    vys = []
    axs = []
    ays = []

    x = np.array([0, 0])    # Position
    v = np.array([0, 0])    # Velocity
    a1 = np.array([1, 0])   # Acceleration in the first phase
    a2 = np.array([0, 1])   # Acceleration in the second phase
    delta_t = 0.01

    t = -5

    # Zeroth phase of the simulation, thrust in x-direction.
    while t < 0:
        x = x + v * delta_t    # Update position with velocity
        t += delta_t           # Advance the time

        # Save coordinates to the lists.
        ts.append(t)
        xs.append(x[0])
        ys.append(x[1])
        vxs.append(v[0])
        vys.append(v[1])
        axs.append(0)
        ays.append(0)

    # First phase of the simulation, thrust in x-direction.
    while t < 10:
        x = x + v * delta_t    # Update position with velocity
        v = v + a1 * delta_t   # Update velocity with current thrust
        t += delta_t           # Advance the time

        # Save coordinates to the lists.
        ts.append(t)
        xs.append(x[0])
        ys.append(x[1])
        vxs.append(v[0])
        vys.append(v[1])
        axs.append(a1[0])
        ays.append(a1[1])

    # Second phase of the simulation, thrust in y-direction.
    while t < 20:
        x = x + v * delta_t    # Update position with velocity
        v = v + a2 * delta_t   # Update velocity with current thrust
        t += delta_t           # Advance the time

        # Save coordinates to the lists.
        ts.append(t)
        xs.append(x[0])
        ys.append(x[1])
        vxs.append(v[0])
        vys.append(v[1])
        axs.append(a2[0])
        ays.append(a2[1])

    # Third phase of the simulation, thrust in y-direction.
    while t < 25:
        x = x + v * delta_t    # Update position with velocity
        t += delta_t           # Advance the time

        # Save coordinates to the lists.
        ts.append(t)
        xs.append(x[0])
        ys.append(x[1])
        vxs.append(v[0])
        vys.append(v[1])
        axs.append(0)
        ays.append(0)

    print(vxs)

    fig1 = pl.figure()

    ax = fig1.add_subplot(3, 2, 1)
    ax.set_title('Position $x$')
    ax.plot(ts, xs)
    ax.margins(0.1)

    ax = fig1.add_subplot(3, 2, 2)
    ax.set_title('Position $y$')
    ax.plot(ts, ys)
    ax.margins(0.1)

    ax = fig1.add_subplot(3, 2, 3)
    ax.set_title('Velocity $x$')
    ax.plot(ts, vxs)
    ax.margins(0.1)

    ax = fig1.add_subplot(3, 2, 4)
    ax.set_title('Velocity $y$')
    ax.plot(ts, vys)
    ax.margins(0.1)

    ax = fig1.add_subplot(3, 2, 5)
    ax.set_title('Acceleration $x$')
    ax.plot(ts, axs)
    ax.margins(0.1)

    ax = fig1.add_subplot(3, 2, 6)
    ax.set_title('Acceleration $y$')
    ax.plot(ts, ays)
    ax.margins(0.1)

    fig1.tight_layout()
    fig1.savefig('fig1.pdf')
    fig1.savefig('fig1.svg')

    fig2 = pl.figure()
    ax = fig2.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    ax.plot(xs, ys)
    ax.set_title('Trajectory')
    ax.set_xlabel('$x$')
    ax.set_ylabel('$y$')
    ax.margins(0.05)
    fig2.tight_layout()
    fig2.savefig('fig2.pdf')
    fig2.savefig('fig2.svg')



def _parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='')
    options = parser.parse_args()

    return options


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate response. I'm still in doubt about centrifugal force. For an outside observer it's inertial system, but for the ship it's non-intertial system, isn't it? The ship is trying to make a turn by applying force along Y, it's not trying to make a circular path, but at each step it's traversing a portion of the elliptical path (whose radius will change with time). Doesn't that make ship's reference frame to be rotating reference frame?

Comment: To frame it differently, how's this motion of the ship in space different from the motion of train/car along a curved path?

Comment: If you apply thrust in $x$ for a while the ship will start to move on a straight line. Then you turn off the thrust in $x$ and instead switch to thrust in $y$. The ship will actually move on a parabola during the acceleration phase. When you stop that thrust as well the ship will again move along a straight line (no acceleration, Newton's first and second axiom). This line will be at a different angle, though. I programmed a simulation for you and I updated my post.

Comment: @Jayesh: The difference between the ship and the car is that the car experiences *friction* from the tires perpendicular to the direction of motion. This is what keeps the car “in track” and provides the centripetal force for the car to drive in a circle. The spaceship does not have any friction.

Comment: The friction from tires (or horizontal component of weight on banked roads) help cancel out the centrifugal force on a car along curved path, but the centrifugal force will exist irrespective of them. If a car tries to turn and the friction with road is not enough to balance the centrifugal force, it will skid off the road. That's why I asked that in case of ship in space, will it have to apply an extra thrust in radially outward direction in order to make a turn.

Comment: You are in a moving system along the *desired* curved path is not an inertial system. And it is not the system of car which is subtle. As you are not in an inertial system, you see fictions forces like the centrifugal force when taking a turn. If the car experiences friction to cancel out the centrifugal force, it will not move *in your frame*. But your frame moves along the desired path, so the car takes the desired path. If there is no friction then the centrifugal force will pull the car away from *your* trajectory and therefore off the road.

Comment: It is all much clearer from an actual inertial system (like you want to use with outside the space ship). There the car stays in linear motion (straight line) unless a force (like friction) acts on it. In the inertial system of the road the friction will act as a centripetal force and push the car on a circle. The spaceship will indeed also have to thrust radially outward to make the turn. Whether the thrust *is* the centripetal force or the thrust cancels the centrifugal force is a matter of reference frame but the same physics. Do you understand this difference? That is the key to it!